# Purple + White Bar in Right Image With Stereo Side By Side Recording + Streaming

Tags: raspberry-pi, picamera, raspivid

I'm using a StereoPi v2 Camera Kit and running the OpenCV OS that came with the pi.

I'm running into an issue where there is a purple and white flickering column in the right image of a side by side stereo recording. This happens with both raspivid, and PiCamera.

Raspivid command I'm using:
`raspivid -o - -t 0 -3d sbs -w 800 -h 600 -fps 12  | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8085/}' :demux=h264`

PiCamera code:

```
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera(stereo_mode="side-by-side")
camera.resolution = (1920, 1088)
camera.start_recording('my_video.h264')
camera.wait_recording(5)
camera.stop_recording()
```

Raspivid result:
https://i.imgur.com/36QQzkG.png

PiCamera result:
https://i.imgur.com/n7e8rUu.png

I've also noticed that sometimes the split between the two images flickers to the right, cutting off some of the right image but revealing some of the left image underneath it. It appears as if the right image is shifted to the left, where the right column is raw memory. To me it seems like a memory issue since it happens with both raspivid and picamera, and only while recording. I'd be happy to provide the h264 files if someone wants to look at them more closely.

Image depicting what I've just described. The shifted part is near the bottom:
https://imgur.com/a/znBTPWJ

The stereo image looks completely fine if a still image is taken, these issues only happen when recording in stereo.

Here's what I've done to try to solve this issue:

- Double checked that my camera is indeed enabled
- apt-get update/upgrade
- updating picamera
- increase cma memory in config.txt to 512mb
- increase gpu memory through raspi-config to 512mb
- swapped cameras left and right through picamera camera_num, but the issues remained on whichever was the right image
- fixed [this](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/411) bug in picamera

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by having my aspect ratio be 4:3 for the picamera code. Later on, I had a similar issue that was then caused by setting the camera.resolution initially then resizing it during a camera.capture_continuous call to the same resolution as was specified before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).